# Unresolved play! dependency: POM instead of JAR

Tags: dependencies, playframework-2.0, sbt

Im working on a play! app using the Neo4j libraries. Neo4j is working fine, but I am trying to set up the server (including web administration) with an embedded database ([following this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-embedded.html)).

My dependencies are:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.8.M06",
  "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06",
  "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" classifier "static-web",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9"
)
```

However, when I run the `update` command, the `neo4j-server-1.8.M06.jar` is missing. Somehow, sbt fetches all jars and the pom file for this dependency:

```
[info] Updating [...]...

[...]

[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j/1.8.M06/neo4j-1.8.M06.pom ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.neo4j#neo4j;1.8.M06!neo4j.pom (758ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.8.M06-static-web.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.neo4j.app#neo4j-server;1.8.M06!neo4j-server.jar (3678ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.sun.jersey#jersey-core;1.9!jersey-core.jar(bundle) (941ms)
[info] downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/1.8.M06/neo4j-kernel-1.8.M06.jar ...

[...]
```

How can I tell sbt to fetch the required jar file? Adding `withSources()` did not solve this problem.

Comment: If you remove the "static-web" dependency, is the `neo4j-server-1.8.M06.jar` file downloaded ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I am then missing the `neo4j-server-1.8.M06-static-web.jar` :)

Comment: And as explained in the doc, did you try `"org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" classifier "static-web"
      from "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.8.M06/-static-web.jar"` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the doc version. I end up with the same result: Either the `neo4j-server-1.8.M06.jar` is missing or the `neo4j-server-1.8.M06-static-web.jar` is missing...

Comment: And by specifying both: `"org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" from "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.‌​8.M06.jar"` and `"org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" classifier "static-web" from "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.‌​8.M06-static-web.jar"` ?

Comment: This failes: `org.neo4j.app#neo4j-server;1.8.M06!neo4j-server.jar` cannot be resolved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working with the following dependencies:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.8.M06",
  "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" classifier "static-web" classifier "",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9"
)
```

The key was the empty `classifier ""`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this by specifying the artefacts exact locations:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.8.M06",
  "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" from "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.8.M06.jar",
  "org.neo4j.app" % "neo4j-server" % "1.8.M06" classifier "static-web" from "http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/1.8.M06/neo4j-server-1.8.M06-static-web.jar",
  "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.9"
)
```

Comment: Strangely enough, specifying the exact locations leads to a resolve error: `sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.neo4j.app#neo4j-server;1.8.M06!neo4j-server.jar`.

Comment: I certainly can add an unmanaged dependency, but I was hoping to get it working as a managed one...